# Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code when flutter run in debug

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

I have a Flutter project which runs perfectly in v2.3.3. I upgraded the flutter version to 3.0.0 in order to use null safety feature. I solved every errors. However when I ran the project, I got **Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code** error. I couldn't find any reasonable and logical solutions throughout internet. Could you please help me on this issue?

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone SE (3rd generation) in debug mode...
Running pod install...                                              5.7s
Running Xcode build...                                                  
Xcode build done.                                           18.1s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    2022-05-16 15:32:57.974 xcodebuild[72650:368105] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionSentinelHostApplications for extension
    Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionHosts.watchOS of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore
    2022-05-16 15:32:57.974 xcodebuild[72650:368105] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionPointIdentifierToBundleIdentifier for extension
    Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionToBundleIdentifierMap.watchOS of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore
    ** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
    Writing result bundle at path:
        /var/folders/00/r0s0tm0x1s33__6xjw2fml1r0000gn/T/flutter_tools.EYRty2/flutter_ios_build_temp_dir7bCY7C/temporary_xcresult_bundle

    ld: warning: linking against a dylib which is not safe for use in application extensions:
    /Users/****/Projects/ES.Online.Mobile/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/XCFrameworkIntermediates/InsiderMobileAdvancedNotification/InsiderMobileAdvancedNotification.framework/Ins
    iderMobileAdvancedNotification
    ld: warning: linking against a dylib which is not safe for use in application extensions:
    /Users/****/Projects/ES.Online.Mobile/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/XCFrameworkIntermediates/InsiderMobileAdvancedNotification/InsiderMobileAdvancedNotification.framework/Ins
    iderMobileAdvancedNotification
    ld: warning: linking against a dylib which is not safe for use in application extensions:
    /Users/****/Projects/ES.Online.Mobile/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/XCFrameworkIntermediates/InsiderMobileAdvancedNotification/InsiderMobileAdvancedNotification.framework/Ins
    iderMobileAdvancedNotification
    ld: warning: linking against a dylib which is not safe for use in application extensions:
    /Users/****/Projects/ES.Online.Mobile/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/XCFrameworkIntermediates/InsiderMobileAdvancedNotification/InsiderMobileAdvancedNotification.framework/Ins
    iderMobileAdvancedNotification

    Failed to package /Users/****/Projects/ES.Online.Mobile.
    Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
    note: Using new build system
    note: Planning
    note: Build preparation complete
    note: Building targets in dependency order
    /Users/****/Projects/ES.Online.Mobile/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of
    supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 15.4.99. (in target 'ReachabilitySwift' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/****/Projects/ES.Online.Mobile/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of
    supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 15.4.99. (in target 'FMDB' from project 'Pods')

    Result bundle written to path:
        /var/folders/00/r0s0tm0x1s33__6xjw2fml1r0000gn/T/flutter_tools.EYRty2/flutter_ios_build_temp_dir7bCY7C/temporary_xcresult_bundle


Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone SE (3rd generation).
```

flutter doctor -v output:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.0.0, on macOS 12.3.1 21E258 darwin-x64, locale en-TR)
    • Flutter version 3.0.0 at /Users/****/Developer/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision ee4e09cce0 (7 days ago), 2022-05-09 16:45:18 -0700
    • Engine revision d1b9a6938a
    • Dart version 2.17.0
    • DevTools version 2.12.2

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
    • Android SDK at /Users/****/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 29.0.2
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b49-5587405)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 13.3.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • CocoaPods version 1.11.3

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 3.5)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin version 41.1.2
    • Dart plugin version 191.8593
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b49-5587405)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.67.1)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.40.0

[✓] Connected device (3 available)
    • iPhone SE (3rd generation) (mobile) • 33A8F736-A4EA-41E7-8567-408A051F9952 • ios            • com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-15-4 (simulator)
    • macOS (desktop)                     • macos                                • darwin-x64     • macOS 12.3.1 21E258 darwin-x64
    • Chrome (web)                        • chrome                               • web-javascript • Google Chrome 101.0.4951.64

[✓] HTTP Host Availability
    • All required HTTP hosts are available

• No issues found!
```

Comment: I have same issue after update flutter to 3.0 and xcode to 13.4

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and resolved it by upgrading a package. Within the spam of warning logs, there was one line that mentioned "Error" instead of "Warning", due to parameter change e.g. in my case for a TextField. I saw the package had an updated version for Flutter 3.0 and reran after upgrading. The warning logs will be still there, but you're app should be running afterwards.

Check for Errors within the Warning Logs thrown by Packages from your pubspec.yaml

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue and I solved in this way:

- Update MacOS
- Update Xcode and command lines tools
- Run `flutter pub upgrade`, `flutter pub get` in the project folder
- Delete podfile.lock in ios folder of the project
- Run `cd ios`, `pod repo update`, `pod install` in the project folder

Comment: I tried these steps but didnt work. Is there any other suggestions? I have been working on this error for weeks.

Comment: @efesezer ever solve the issue? I have been fighting same thing for a few days now.

Comment: @RobertFlesch open your .xcworkspace file in Xcode. Change target versions of pods that are mentioned in error message to 9.0 and try to run again. It may work like this.

Comment: I ended up "fixing it" by just upgrading to flutter 3.05 and the latest version of xcode. Nothing else I tried for a week would correct the error.